# Helpstring in argparse, each string from new line

Tags: python, docstring

I am doing a CLI utility. When adding a docstring to call help for the module with the function `-- help` in console, I was faced with the fact that all the added text is displayed as a continuous, unbreakable message. How to separate strings from each other? I tried to add `\n` at the end of the line, but this does not work.

```
def createParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='samplefind',
        description="""
        Script to search for matches by word or lines in a text file and save the found information in a new outfile.txt file.
        From command line run python sfind.py .
        To view all available options: python sfind.py -h .
        """
```

Comment: That is not a `docstring` in the usual sense. Please change your title to `help` string in `argparse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter) to retain all spaces in your help string. This is the `argparse` application help string, not a `docstring`. Could look a bit ugly though:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='samplefind',
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
        description="""
        Script to search for matches by word or lines in a text file and save the found information in a new outfile.txt file.
        From command line run python sfind.py .
        To view all available options: python sfind.py -h .
        """)
```

From terminal:

> > py bla.py -h usage: samplefind [-h]
>
> ```
>     Script to search for matches by word or lines in a text file and save the found information in a new outfile.txt file.
>     From command line run python sfind.py .
>     To view all available options: python sfind.py -h .
> ```

Do note that this include spaces from the beginning of line, new lines, everything.

Comment: @lepiloff In what way does it not work? Are you using an IDE? Did you try to `print(thefunc.__doc__)` and it did not produce newlines? Or use it in `help(thefunc)`?

Comment: `print(thefunc.__doc__)` return None

Comment: @lepiloff you completely changed the question. That is not a `docstring`. I will edit.